# Existence of solution of Poisson equation for a square with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

Assume we have that problem:
$$
- \nabla ^ 2 u = f
$$
$$
u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0, \Omega = [0, 1] ^2
$$
The question is what are the natural sufficient conditions on $f$ for the classical solution to exist.

Is it enough for $f$ to be continuous on its domain? $f \in C^1(\Omega)$?

I would like to see some reference if possible.

I am only aware about the existence of the weak solution for the case of $f \in L^2(\Omega)$.

Comment: Any text on elliptic PDE should help you. If you continue with the $L^p$ theory then you'll want to use the Sobolev embedding - whenever $k,p$ are such that $W^{k,p} \hookrightarrow C^0$, elliptic regularity estimates (see e.g. Gilbarg & Trudinger chapter 8) tell us that it suffices for $f$ to have regularity $W^{k-2,p}$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis Thank you!